# Объект или субъект действия, выраженный в словосочетании

Tags: грамматика, семантика, определения, дополнение

1а. *Убийство отца было расследовано.*

1б. *Его убийство было расследовано*.

2а. *Потеря отца была горькой.*

2б. *Его потеря была горькой.*

**Вопросы**

1. Я правильно понимаю, что во всех примерах отец может быть как объектом действия, так и субъектом и нужный смысл определяется читателем исходя из логики ситуации и контекста?
2. В случае когда имеется в виду объект, можно ли вообще в роли дополнения использовать личное местоимение и ставить его перед словом, к которому это дополнение относятся? *Его убийство, его потеря, его задержание, его эксплуатация, его знание, его понимание.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы правильно понимаете первую часть вопроса. Действительно,  «отец может быть как объектом действия, так и субъектом, и нужный смысл определяется читателем исходя из логики ситуации и контекста».

Сравним предложения: (1) ***Автор написал книгу***.   (2) ***Отец потерял сына.*** ***Сын потерял отца.***

**Предложение 1.** Автор (чего?) книги – это родительный  падеж объекта действия. Книга (чья?)  автора – это родительный падеж субъекта действия, значение принадлежности  (притяжательное значение).

Здесь используются  обычные существительные, по их семантике мы различаем значения падежей даже в словосочетаниях.

**Предложения 2.** Потеря (кого?)  отца – это родительный  падеж объекта действия (потерян отец).  Потеря (чья?)  отца (потерял отец) – это родительный падеж субъекта действия, значение принадлежности.

Здесь используется **отглагольное** существительное, поэтому без контекста мы не можем различить падежи.  В то же время такое различение является обязательным требованием, в противном случае это будет считаться стилистической погрешностью текста.

2. В такой же ситуации может находиться **местоимение *ЕГО*.** В значении объекта действия это будет падежная форма личного местоимения, а в значении субъекта действия это будет несклоняемое притяжательное местоимение.

**Различаются** варианты также по контексту. Что касается **позиции** местоимения, то она будет **свободной** в обоих случаях и зависит от актуального членении предложения,  от расстановки логических ударений в нем.

В то же время **частотность вариантов разная.** Вариант с объектным значением "потеря его" наиболее частотен, это его **нормальная** позиция. Субъектное значение "его потеря" встречается реже, так же редко можно увидеть **инверсию** для обоих вариантов.

Все эти выводы неочевидны, но сделать их помогает **Нацкорпус** – достаточно просмотреть там сочетания «его потеря»  и  «потеря его».

**Значение субъекта действия** (потерял он):

«Как жена, там царь рыдает...**Велика его** потеря! Ах, моя Альама!» (речь  идет о взятии крепости). Царю кажется, что **потеря его** невосполнима.

**Значение объекта действия** (потеряли его)

Безвременная **потеря его** была тяжка для художественного мира.  Он умер в цвете лет! О, как тяжела была для меня **его потеря**!

Comment: Всё чётко расписали, спасибо)